# How to solve this CodeIgniter error message? "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in CodeIgniter"

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-query-builder

I am testing the app I created for possible potential bugs and fixing some security holes into it. It came across my mind to check the database and table of the app exist and if it does it runs the code and if the tables does not exist, it will echo a warning message. However, whenever I am testing a feature, I am getting an error saying, **Trying to get property 'project_name' of non-object.** Here is the code in my model to which I am testing if the table and column exist:

```
public function get_project($id){
            if ($this->db->field_exists('id','projects') == FALSE) {

                $this->db->where('id', $id);

                $query = $this->db->get('projects');

                    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                        return $query->row();   
                    }return false;
            }else{
                echo "Table and column does not exist!";
            }
        }
```

As you can see, the line where in I am testing if the field exist where the value is **FALSE** in order for me to display the error warning in the **else** statement. However, whenever I am doing this, I am getting an error saying **Trying to get property 'project_name' of non-object** in my views. Here is the code in my view:

```
    <h3>Project Name:<?php echo $project_data->project_name; ?></h3>
    <h3>Date Created:<?php echo $project_data->date_created; ?><h3>
    <h3>Description:</h3>
    <p class='projects-description'>
        <?php echo $project_data->project_body; ?>
    </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have the wrong testing for the field if it is exist or not,

please change this line from:

```
if ($this->db->field_exists('id','projects') == FALSE) {
```

To

```
if ($this->db->field_exists('id','projects') != FALSE) {
```

then you will be good to go!

Edit, Surround the above code inside

```
if ($this->db->table_exists('yourtablename') )
{
  // table exists
}
else
{
  // table does not exist
}
```

Comment: I did try your suggestion but when I tried, it is not giving me the warning message that I am creating in the **else** statement instead displaying a **Database Error Message**

Comment: exactly, now what is the error message, can you post it?

Comment: This is the error message displaying **A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1146

Table 'errand_db.project' doesn't exist

SHOW COLUMNS FROM `project`

Filename: D:/xampp/htdocs/code_igniter/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691** instead of the **else** statement I am creating

Comment: @RayA seem to be right. Your table called `projects`? (look at the name in the error).
Also, consider the case where the table and column exist but no ID -> then the function return false -> no object...

Comment: I see your point, @DavidWinder. But what if the column name or table truly does not exist? I want to throw a message if that column name or table name does not exist instead of displaying the default database error of CodeIgniter if the table does not exist

Comment: check the updates I did in my answer, you should confirm the table existence first, then columns comes next

Comment: i can understand you wanting to do this if the system was dynamic, but to me it doesn't make any sense as `projects` is hardcoded hence the table at the very least should exist as should the id field. this is a lot of extra querying for no particular reason. i would just do `if ($query && $query->num_rows() > 0)` remove the field exists and call it a day. db_debug would be off in prod env and $query would return false if the table or field didn't exist

Answer (score 0):

you have  wrong if statement it is true or blank,
please change this line :

```
      if ($this->db->field_exists('id','projects')==FALSE) {
```

use this line

```
       if ($this->db->field_exists('id','projects')) {
```

here ..

```
       public function get_project($id){

        if ($this->db->field_exists('id','projects')) { //its already check true 

            $this->db->where('id', $id);

            $query = $this->db->get('projects');

                if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                    return $query->row();   
                }return false;
        }else{
            echo "Table and column does not exist!";
        }
    }
```

}